# how to update Rails 5.2 credential and master key in deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, credentials

Upgrading Rails 4 app to Rails 5.2, got confused about the new master key and credential approach to manage secret variables. Did quite some search in google, but can't find the answer.

My understanding is that in local development,

- A master key will be generated at config/master.key, NOT committed to git repo.
- It is used to encrypt the secret variables in config/credentials.yml.enc.
- I can add or update secret variables through EDITOR=vim rails credentials:edit

So in local development, I add the db password into the config/credentials.yml.enc, and committed into git repo. (Note: it is my local database password.)

But questions come in following two scenarios:

1. Another developer checks out the code, and tries to run in his local environment. It will fail because he does not have the master key. Even I can share the master key to him through some other approaches, it still have the assumption that his local db password is the same as mine, which is usually not the truth. And it does not make sense for him to change the secret variable values and commit again. So how it would work in multi developer collaboration?
2. It becomes more critical when come to production deployment. The secret variables in production environment should be different with local development environments. Then how to change the secret variable values during deployment? e.g. how to automate EDITOR=vim rails credentials:edit, like by some shell script?

I think both questions should be naive ones, these are typical scenarios, and must have been considered, but it really confuses me... Please help me understand, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe you can reference environment variables inside the encrypted credentials. So leave your `database.yml` file to use ENV and *not* the encrypted credentials under the **development** heading. You can assign the credentials per environment in `application.rb` using a CONSTANT like `ENCRYPTED_CREDENTIALS`. Then, use `ENCRYPTED_CREDENTIALS` in `database.yml` under the **production** heading.

These two files plus your encrypted credentials should look as follows (shortened for brevity). Notice how the encrypted credentials only use **production** because `database.yml` **development** heading isn't using encrypted credentials:

---

### config/application.rb

```rb
ENCRYPTED_CREDENTIALS = Rails.application.credentials[Rails.env.to_s.to_sym]
```

### config/database.yml

```yaml
development:
  username: <%= ENV["DATABASE_USER"] %>

production:
  username: ENCRYPTED_CREDENTIALS[:database_user]
```

### `rails credentials:show`

```yaml
production:
  database_user: some_username
```